# Bar height taking up entire height of viewBox responsive SVG

Tags: d3.js

I'm still fairly new to D3.js. Right now, I'm working on making a responsive bar chart. I'm using the viewbox to make it responsive in a div and using the DOM to set the height and width to the offsetWidth/Height of the div.

But the bars seem to be incorrect in height when set to the yScale.

Here's a screenshot of how they end up appearing:

[image]

I'm also being thrown this error in the console:

"d3.min.js:2 Error:  attribute height: A negative value is not valid. ("-78.69462281846592")"

I believe the error has to do with this part of the code where I set the height attr to the height subtracted by the yScale data value:

```
      var bars = svg.selectAll('.bar')
    .data(data)
    .enter()
    .append('rect')
    .attr('class', 'bar')
    .attr('x', function(d) {
      return xScale(d.Year);
    })
    .attr('y', function(d) {
      return yScale(d.Total);
    })
    .attr('width', xScale.bandwidth())
    .attr('height', function(d) {
      return height - yScale(d.Total);
    });
```

Here's the entire function that's drawing the bar chart:

```
  <style>
    #barchart {
      width: 75vw;
      height: 50vh;
    }
  </style>
```

```
function draw(data) {

  var width = document.getElementById('barchart').offsetWidth,
    height = document.getElementById('barchart').offsetHeight;

  var svg = d3.select('#barchart')
    .append('svg')
    .attr('width', '100%')
    .attr('height', '100%')
    .attr('viewBox', '0 0 ' + width + ' ' + height)
    .append('g');

  var xScale = d3.scaleBand()
    .range([0, width])
    .padding(0.4);

  var yScale = d3.scaleLinear()
    .range([height, 0]);

  xScale.domain(data.map(function(d) {
    return d.Year;
  }));

  yScale.domain(data.map(function(d) {
    return d.Total;
  }));

  var x_xaxis = svg.append('g')
    .attr('transform', 'translate(' + 0 + ',' + 370 + ')')
    .call(d3.axisBottom(xScale));

  var y_axis = svg.append('g')
    .attr('transform', 'translate(' + 20 + ',' + 0 + ')')
    .call(d3.axisLeft(yScale)
      .ticks(100));

  var bars = svg.selectAll('.bar')
    .data(data)
    .enter()
    .append('rect')
    .attr('class', 'bar')
    .attr('x', function(d) {
      return xScale(d.Year);
    })
    .attr('y', function(d) {
      return yScale(d.Total);
    })
    .attr('width', xScale.bandwidth())
    .attr('height', function(d) {
      return height - yScale(d.Total);
    });


}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without seeing your data it's tough to give a full answer but I'm certain the problem is that your `yScale` domain is being set incorrectly.  Its linear so it needs an array of `[minValue, maxValue]`, you are giving it an array of all data values.  Try setting it with [extent](https://github.com/d3/d3-array#extent):

```
yScale.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) {
  return d.Total;
}));
```

Looking through this you want to start at zero, so:

```
yScale.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) {
  return d.Total;
})]);
```

Also, you need to define the margins a bit more concretely.  Take a look at these [modifications](http://plnkr.co/edit/6jLFP5FXNeCJnEp4UZGu?p=preview).

Comment: @rainbowunicorn, see edits above and link to plunker.